# How do I configure webpack to bundle files that are not being imported in code?

Tags: webpack, bundle

I have a third-party-provided CSS file (that I can't modify) that expects some font files to be in a specific folder.

Initially, I used a file-loader but as these fonts aren't being referenced or imported anywhere inside my code, they aren't being bundled when I `npm run build`, and file-loader doesn't seem to have an option to bundle them anyway...

I also looked for other loaders that export the files no matter what but I haven't found anything useful.

What would you do here? Is there any other loader that I don't know of that could help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a module rule to use [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) with your vendor styles. It will resolve `url` and `@import` names as requests using webpack's module resolver. This will then allows you to configure the correct loaders for the vendor's font files.